# BBEdit - how to move sidebar from left to right side of screen

Tags: ui, bbedit

I'm currently using BBedit 14 and I can't find any option to move the sidebar from the left side of the screen to the right. In earlier versions the default was for the sidebar to be on the right and I prefer that arrangement.

According to [this old Macworld article](https://www.macworld.com/article/201387/bbeditdrawer.html) there is supposed to be a value in the **com.barebones.bbedit plist** file that controls this option, but when I read this file using defaults the suggested key **MultiDocumentWindows** doesn't appear to exist any more.

Thank you in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: Did you reach out to BBEdit already about this? What was their response?

Comment: No, not yet. I've looked at the user manual and their "Expert Preferences" reference article but there's no details about changing the sidebar position as far as I can tell. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious before I start bothering their support department.

Comment: Support Departments exist to be bothered!